# Awesome-wm and YouTube (html5) window issue

Tags: awesome-wm

As a rule for Firefox, I have every window automatically start maximized (not fullscreen).

The window is horizontally and vertically maximized, with the awesome panel up top.

However, if I go to YouTube and decide on making the video fullscreen, and then afterwards exit fullscreen, the Firefox window loses its maximized state.

I have searched this, but all the info I can find is about YouTube back when it used the flash player.

In summary:

1. Maximized
2. Fullscreen (manually initiated by me)
3. Unmaximized (after exiting the YouTube fullscreen video. Wish it stayed maximized like it was at step 1)

**Here is my rule for Firefox:**

```
    { rule_any = { class = {"Firefox", "firefox" } },
  properties = { maximized_vertical = true, maximized_horizontal = true, size_hints_honor = false, floating = false },
```

Comment: Why not setting the layout to maximize? Also Unix StackExchange is a more proper place to post.

Comment: Do you have another monitor? If not, can you get a terminal window open and run xprop on the web browser window before and after?